# What's kubernetes abbreviation for deployments?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

For `kubectl describe` I can abbreviate a few classes of resources, for example:

```
po/xxx -> pods/xxx
rs/xxx -> replicasets/xxx
```

Where can I find the full list?

I'm trying to find the abbreviation for deployments.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To get a full list of your resources, including their *shortname*, use:

```
kubectl api-resources
```

e.g. Deployment has the shorthname `deploy`.

---

Example output from `kubectl api-resources`:

```
NAME         SHORTNAMES APIVERSION   NAMESPACED KIND
daemonsets   ds         apps/v1      true       DaemonSet
deployments  deploy     apps/v1      true       Deployment
replicasets  rs         apps/v1      true       ReplicaSet
statefulsets sts        apps/v1      true       StatefulSet
...
```

Comment: this gives a good list of top level aliases,
but the expansion of svc in "kubectl create svc" is diff from "kubectl get svc"

is there a way to get any level expansion,
if possible, is there a way to show the expanded kubectl command 

for eg, kubectl create svc ...
how can the expanded form kubectl create service ... be shown as well

Answer (score 4):

The kubernetes abbreviation for deployment is `deploy`

Abbreviations or shorthand for other kubernetes objects are as follows:

```
certificates = cert, certs
certificiaterequests = cr, crs
certificatesigningrequests = csr
componentstatuses = cs
configmaps = cm
cronjobs = cj
customresourcedefinitions = crd, crds
daemonsets = ds
deployments = deploy
endpoints = ep
events = ev
horizontalpodautoscalers = hpa
ingresses = ing
limitranges = limits
namespaces = ns
networkpolicies = netpol
nodes = no
persistentvolumes = pv
persistentvolumeclaims = pvc
pods = po
podsecuritypolicies = psp
priorityclasses = pc
replicationcontrollers = rc
replicasets = rs
resourcequotas = quota
scheduledscalers = ss
services = svc
serviceaccounts = sa
statefulsets = sts
storageclasses = sc
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).