# Kubectl show expanded command when using alases or shorthand

Tags: kubectl

Kubectl has many aliases like svc, po, deploy etc.
Is there a way to show the expanded command for a command with shorthand.

for example `kubectl get po`
to
`kubectl get pods`

On a similar question the api-resources is used @ [What's kubernetes abbreviation for deployments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72465216/whats-kubernetes-abbreviation-for-deployments)

But it gives very top level shorthands,
for eg, `kubeclt get svc` expands to `kubectl get services`
but in `kubectl create svc` expands to `kubectl create service`

Kindly guide,
Thanks

Comment: What is the question

Comment: to show the expanded command 
for eg, kubectl get po would give the list of pods

i was hoping that it would show the kubectl get pods, then would list the pods

Answer (score 1):

[`kubectl explain`](https://jamesdefabia.github.io/docs/user-guide/kubectl/kubectl_explain/) may be of interest e.g.:

```bash
kubectl explain po

KIND:     Pod
VERSION:  v1

DESCRIPTION:
     Pod is a collection of containers that can run on a host. This resource is
     created by clients and scheduled onto hosts.
```

There are [plugins](https://krew.sigs.k8s.io/plugins/) for `kubectl` too.

I've not tried it but [`kubectl explore`](https://github.com/keisku/kubectl-explore) may be worth a try.

Unfortunately, `kubectl` isn't documented by [`explainshell.com`](https://explainshell.com/) which would be a boon as it would also document the various flags e.g. `-n` (`--namespace`) and `-o` (`--output`).